# How do I default the Azure `az` cli to use `--query [].name`?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

The `az` cli list commands are pretty verbose by default. To get around that, I'm constantly adding a simple query of `--query [].name` to each `az` cli call, or a `--output table` option, but that's a lot of redundant typing.

Is there any way to get the `az` cli to add a `--query` or `--output` option by default? Or some other way to have the `az` cli list commands to default to a simpler output?

For example, I'd like for any `az x list` command to default to `az x list --query [].name` showing something like this:

```
[
    "vm-1-name",
    "vm-2-name",
    "vm-3-name"
]
```

Or to default to `az x list --output table`, showing something like this:

```
Name    ResourceGroup    Location    Zones
------  ---------------  ----------  -------
vm-1    res-group        centralus
vm-2    res-group        centralus
vm-3    res-group        centralus
```

I tried setting a default using `az configure --defaults query=[].name`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried `az configure --defaults output=table`, but no difference there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the `--default` parameter does not support them, available configuration keys [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration?view=azure-cli-latest#cli-configuration-with-az-configure).

To meet your requirement, you can configure the CLI configuration file.

1.Find the `config` file, the configuration file itself is located at `$AZURE_CONFIG_DIR/config`. The default value of `AZURE_CONFIG_DIR` is `$HOME/.azure` on Linux and macOS, and `%USERPROFILE%\.azure` on Windows.

2.Add the part as below to the file, save it.

```
[core]
output = table
```

[image]

3.Then the output will be like below, no need to use `--output table`.

[image]

Comment: That did it, thanks! For completion, to temporarily "undo" it and get the verbose output back, add `--output json` to the list command.

Comment: Is there a way to set the default `output = table` for *only* list commands, for example? For show commands, verbosity by default is preferred.

Comment: @CivFan AFAIK, you can't.